# strange workflow in ado.net with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

i had assigned a job for insert,update, delete operation in a table for my student. he had done this assignment fine. but his code is made me crazy that he wrote update code like below

Working sample:

```
Public Function Toeditdetails(ByVal item As Boolean)

        If item = True Then

            Dim con As SqlConnection
            'Dim retval As Integer

            con = New SqlConnection(conn)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            cmd = New SqlCommand("updatelogin", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value() = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@user_password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)).Value() = TextBox2.Text.Trim()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nameofuser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value() = TextBox3.Text.Trim()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@contact_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)).Value() = TextBox4.Text.Trim()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)).Value() = TextBox5.Text.Trim()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@joiningdate", SqlDbType.Date)).Value() = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@usergroup_id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value() = SelectedID(ComboBox1.Text)

            If item = True Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value() = Label9.Text.Trim()
            End If

            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dst As New DataSet
            da.Fill(dst)

            If dst.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dst.Tables(0)
            End If

            If Not cmd Is Nothing Then
                cmd.Dispose()
            End If
        End If

End Function
```

Note there is no ExecuteNonQuery() method for his SqlCommand object and he didn't call this method in entire project. when i call function result still updating... how its happen? anyone genius can you explain whats going on above statement? any help would be appreciated

Regards and thanks
Sarva

Comment: It's a stored procedure

Comment: yes  OneFineDay. please read my comment in first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `Toeditdetails` method it will execute stored procedure called `updatelogin`

check the stored procedure and you may able to find why you receive updated result. Stored procedure several statements like below

```
update table1 set username ='test1' where uid =@uid;
select * from table1;
```

when you call stored procedure with above code you will get the table1 data but `update` statement will update data before you receive it.

Comment: i agree with you Damith . but he didn't call there cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). so only im confused. it should not affect until call this cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() statement. but it works . how?

Comment: when you call `da.Fill(dst)` that Stored procedure will execute and fetch the data, no need to call `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: thanks for your reply and i didn't noticed that sorry